# SSR_SetUserTmpStr in zkemkeeper.dll returns Error Code: -100

Tags: zkemkeeper

I'm using VB.NET to copy fingerprint template from one device to another. I've successfully pulled fingerprint template from the origin device using SSR_GetUserTmpStr. However, when set the fingerprint template to destination device using SSR_SetUserTmpStr returns -100.

SSR_SetUserInfo was successfull and the new user was registered at the destination device.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

use SetUserTmpExStr

```
axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(1, false);
axCZKEM1.SetUserTmpExStr(1, userid.ToString(), FingerIndex, 1, TmpData)
axCZKEM1.RefreshData(1);
axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(1, true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).